# How to set bash interpreter path in IntelliJ

Tags: bash, plugins, intellij-idea, path, interpreter

I am wondering which path should be set in "Interpreter path" area in Run/Debug Configurations in IntelliJ, to complie and run bash script.

Using IntelliJ 15.0.3 on Windows 7

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You must have a shell installed.

I have [Git](https://git-scm.com/download/win) installed, so I use the path to the git shell.

Something like `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe`.

I use also the `--login -i` flags for the "Interpreter options" field.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use the Windows CMD.exe you have to set:

- Interpreter path: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\CMD.exe` (or wherever your cmd.exe is located)
- Interpreter options: `/C`
- Working directory: `path/to/your/project`

in the IntelliJ run config.

(Tested with IntelliJ 2017.3)

Comment: What does the `/K` means? I dont found any info about the Interpreter options

Comment: `/K` is a switch for *Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.* (source: https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html). I don't know why exactly it's needed but it didn't work for me without it.

Comment: `/K` option will keep IDEA configuration running even after script is done. It's better to use `/C` instead: it will run script and finish properly.

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu,
Interrupter path can be set to: `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2):

For gitbash as your interpreter i found 2 ways

1.- For "BashSupport" plugin in intellij

- Type Ctrl + Alt + S to go to settings
  Search for Bash Support or go to "Languages & Frameworks->BashSupport" 
  In "Default Interpreter" put the path for gitbash
  C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
- Then right click on the script to run and click on Edit script
  Then click in "Use project interpreter" 
  Then in "Interpreter options" put
  --login -i --

2.- For "Shell Script" plugin in Intellij

- First set gitbash as your terminal
  Ctrl + Alt + S to go to settings
  Search for Terminal or go to "Tools->Terminal"
  In "Shell path" put
  C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
- Then Right click on the script to run and click on Edit script
  Then in "Interpreter path" put
  C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe
  Then in "Interpreter options" put
  -login -i --

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 you can also use PowerShell.

- Interpreter path: `c:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
- Interpreter options: `-Command`
- Working directory: path/to/your/project