# Unable to run Shell script in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: git, shell, intellij-idea, interpreter

I saw **ALL** the other answers on stack overflow but none of them helped me.
**What all I have done till now**
[IntelliJ IDEA: Running a shell script as a Run/Debug Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15203498/intellij-idea-running-a-shell-script-as-a-run-debug-configuration)
[How to set bash interpreter path in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35628012/how-to-set-bash-interpreter-path-in-intellij)
The Shell script code I am using is 100% correct.
[image: Config]

[image: Terminal Output]

Can anybody help me where I am going wrong, I have tried many times with different solutions.

Comment: I THINK I WOULD HAVE TO PUT BOUNTY.

Comment: git bash exe does not know these arguments. If you need to specify them, see https://superuser.com/q/1104567 Otherwise just specify the interpreter path to git bash exe and path to a script to run.

Comment: @Andrey I specified interpreter path to bash.exe and other path to script to run only. I didn't get your solution, can you just tell me a solution for running shell files in intellij terminal